# Tricolor graph, reality check

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have $nodes=111$ - $1,2,3...111$

Node is connected to another node if(two cases):

Nodes product is divisable by 3, but not divisible by 9 (thus $3$ and $5$ connected $3$ and $21$ are not)
Nodes product is divisable by 2, but not divisible by 4 or 6 (thus $2$ and $5$ connected, but $2$ and $26$ are not)

Question is - if is this graph has 3-coloring.

I am not very familiar with graph theory, so please check if my considerations are sane.

We have three types of nodes.

Type 1: $4,6,8,9,12...$ - those nodes has absolutely no connections to other nodes, and shouldnt be considered. Those always fit, if other are able to be tricolored.

Type 2: $p \in \mathbb{P}$ like $1,5,7,11,13..$ (without $2,3$!)

Type 3: $2p|p \in \mathbb{P}$ or $3p|p \in \mathbb{P}$, like $2, 3, 10, 14, 15, 21...$. Nodes like $70=2*5*7$ also belong here. In other words type 3 is composite, with only one (either $2$ or) $3$ as a factor.

All nodes of type 2 is connected to all nodes of type 3 and vice versa. No node of type 2 is connected to another node of type 2 (it will violate divisibility by either $2$ or $3$ for product). Neither any node of type 3 is interconnected, because it will inject $2*2$, $2*3$ or $3*3$ restriction.

Now onto coloring. Type 1 - whatever, lets say $R$.
Type 2 - $G$.
Type 3 - $R$.

Each node of type 2($G$) has only neighbours of type 3($R$) and vice versa. Type 1 nodes has neighbors at all, and dont break tricolorability.

Actually it is bicolor graph, in my opinion.

Are my thoughts correct about original question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Here is a somewhat slicker way to write it up.

Let $V=\{1,2,\ldots,111\}$. For each $k\in V$ let $\varphi(k)$ be the number of factors of $2$ plus the number of factors of $3$ in the prime factorization of $k$. Your Type $1$ nodes are the $k\in V$ such that $\varphi(k)\ge 2$; your Type $2$ nodes are the $k\in V$ such that $\varphi(k)=0$; and your Type $3$ nodes are the $k\in V$ such that $\varphi(k)=1$. Call these sets of nodes $V_2,V_0$, and $V_1$, respectively.

Then if $k\in V_j$ and $\ell\in V_j$, nodes $k$ and $\ell$ are connected by an edge if and only if $i+j=1$. Clearly this means that each node of $V_0$ is connected to each node of $V_1$, and there are no other edges. Thus, we need one color for $V_0$ and another for $V_1$, and each node in $V_2$ can receive either of those colors.

In fact the graph is simply the complete bipartite graph $K_{|V_0|,|V_1|}$ together with $|V_2|$ isolated vertices.